# How to animate Scroll Viewer to smooth scroll?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi was wondering what method or what to use to make a Scroll Viewer scroll on it own and smoothly.

I'm using a timer to make the Scroll Viewer Scroll on the timers tick event with ScrollViewer.LineDown(). The only thing is this makes it jump down line by line on the tick event. I basically need something that scrolls idk say 100px every second untill its down to the bottom or something like that. Everytime I google I keep finding the same answers that don't apply to me, maybe. Because making "CanContentScroll=False" isn't really what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"` can help:

```
  <ListBox VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"  
                  Name="lv" >
```

Assuming that you can find the ScrollViewer:

```
ScrollViewer sv =  GetChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(lv);
Task timerTask = ScrollPeriodically(sv, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
```

in which

```
    async Task ScrollPeriodically(ScrollViewer sv, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset + 1);
            await Task.Delay(interval, token);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1255753/WPF-Easiest-Way-to-Create-a-Animated-Smoothed-Scro) is what you're looking for.

Quick Way:

- Add offset dependency parameter manually to **scrollviewer**.
- Duplicate your scrollviewr
- Use an animator.

Read that article, it's very detailed !

Comment: Thank you for the input. When I get a chance I will look into it. For now I already discovered another way.